# android popup window clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, onclicklistener

Hi I have a android PopupWindow which has a RelativeLayout containing two TextView and one ImageView.I want to be able to click on the the Popup as a whole with the respective views inside it and go to another activity.Do I need to implement a custom OnClickListener on the popup or there are some methods on the popup window I am missing out on.Please guide me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the methods are you missing? edit it clearly

Answer (score 1):

`PopupWindow` does not inherit from `View`, so you will need to implement your own click listener. [This method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setTouchInterceptor) might help.